# Sharing link on Facebook does not show caption or description

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an app that shares links to facebook. This link comes with a description and a caption. The problem I have is that the caption and description does not show up on facebook, sometimes a totally different caption is shown that I think is the site (link) description.

using facebookSDK this is how I share:

```
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) 
{
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
    name:params.name
        caption:params.caption
        description:params.description
        picture:params.picture
        clientState:nil
        handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) 
        {
            if(error) 
            {
                 NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
            } else {
                // Success
                NSLog(@"result %@", results);
            }
}];
```

}

I have another app that uses the same exact code and the caption shows just fine. I don't get it LOL help please

Comment: found any solution? I have the same problem...